# similar function as gotoxy and print a line on HP TANDEM - GUARDIAN

Tags: c, tandem

I am working in Guardian environment of HP tandem machines through C programming. Can any one please let me know a function which i can use to print output by moving to an X row and Y column. like a curses library on Guardian.

When i try to include  it does not recognize it.

Comment: Could you please share some of your code, command-to-compile, what-are-the-compile-time-errors-you-get, etc. OTOH, are you including the correct libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your terminals are 6530 terminals (or users are running 6530 emulation), then you need to use the standard Guardian I/O procedure calls (WRITE, READ, WRITEREAD, CONTROL, SETMODE) and send the relevant control code, escape sequences and display data to the terminal.

The curses library doesn't have an equivalent on Guardian unless you can find a third party product.

A good reference for this type of work is the 6530 Programmers Guide - Google for that. There is also a brief tutorial on escape sequences [here](http://goanand.com/tandem/escape_sequences.pdf)